# Only use cached login if active directory isn't available

Tags: windows, active-directory, login

Is it possible to set up my clients so that they can login at any time, always asking Active Directory first and if it isn't available use Windows cache?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've changed the defaults, workstations and member servers already cache the last 10 logons.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852209(v=ws.11).aspx
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
Interactive logon: Number of previous logons to cache

Comment: I'm aware of that. But the thing is that when I update accounts (eg. disabling them) they can still log in with their cached credentials. So I want it to ignore the cache if a DC is available and use it when it isn't.